# Lost ETH - Don't remember which wallet was used?

Tags: wallets

A year ago I had bought some ETH using a wallet I don't remember. All I have is a **password** and a **contract address** `0x03530cC59c873F88EDe35036D3448B450A41381a`.

If you see the contract creator there seems to be some balance there.

Any ideas how I can restore the ETH to a wallet (or which wallet it could be)?

Answer (score 1):

I just checked that address. You created a wallet contract, but you didn't send any ETH to that address. Your ETH is still at the address that created that wallet, 0x8c60f6d96e31f65f3f7679bea6ba6ecf2ca51d38. You need the private key, keystore file, or mnemonic phrase for that address to be able to control your ETH.

It's hard to tell what wallet you used, but I'm fairly sure it was one you would download (Parity or Ethereum Wallet) and not a browser based one like MEW. If it was one you downloaded, then if you still have it on your computer, then you should have control of the account.

Comment: Thanks! Yes it was certainly a downloaded exe on Windows. I see Shapeshift at the creator address so perhaps it could be wallet supporting that? I think the ETH was bought with some BTC. I only have a less than 20char password.

Comment: No problem. I believe the only downloaded wallets that support shapeshift are Jaxx and Exodus. I hope you find the wallet!!